# Change element array when the data is not certain index position

Tags: javascript

I am learning javascript array of objects, when I fetch the data from API sometimes I get data from the API in an uncertain index position, for example like this:

```
[
  {formatted_name: 'central_java', name: 'Central Java'},
  {formatted_name: 'east_java', name: 'East Java'},
  {formatted_name: 'west_java', name: 'West Java'},
];
```

sometimes like this:

```
[
  {formatted_name: 'east_java', name: 'East Java'},
  {formatted_name: 'central_java', name: 'Central Java'},
  {formatted_name: 'west_java', name: 'West Java'},
];
```

Sometimes like this too:

```
[
  {formatted_name: 'west_java', name: 'West Java'},
  {formatted_name: 'central_java', name: 'Central Java'},
  {formatted_name: 'east_java', name: 'East Java'},
];
```

What I want to ask is how do I create a condition or change the position of the array element when I get data from the fetch API so that `formatted_name: 'east_java'` is always indexed to 0?

I have tried this code but it doesn't work:

```
function insertAndShift(arr, from, to) {
  let cutOut = arr.splice(from, 1)[0];
  arr.splice(to, 0, cutOut);
}
```

When using the code above, the code cannot be flexible because `formatted_name: 'east_java'` is always uncertain what index is it on. What should I do?

Comment: why there is a need for shifting an array of elements just loop through it instead

Comment: Hey, so the values got from the API is same, right? Only the values indexing are not proper.

Comment: @DevSavata if it has been looped, then how do you make `east_java` always be index to 0?

Comment: @Akashprajapati yes, the values is always the same, only the indexing are not proper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the below code:

```js
test = [
      {formatted_name:'west_java', name:'West Java'}, 
      {formatted_name:'central_java', name:'Central Java'},
      {formatted_name: 'east_java', name:'East Java'},
];
test.forEach(function(value, key) {
if (value.formatted_name == "east_java"){
    test.splice(key, 1);
    test.unshift(value)
}
});
console.log(test);
```